# SQL: Except Join on multiple queries

Tags: sql, join

Getting a bit stuck trying to build this query. **(SQL SERVER)**

I'm trying to join two tables on similar rows, but then stack the unique rows from both table 1 and table 2 on the result set. I was first shooting for a full outer join, but it leaves my key fields blank when the data comes from only one of the tables.

**Example:** [Full Outer Join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/576bc/4)

Here's what I would like for the query to be able to do:

[image: Joining And Stacking Tables]

Essentially, I would like to have a result table where the key fields (Part and Operation) are all returned in two columns (so like a union), but the Estimated and Actual Rate columns returned side by side where there is a matching row between table 1 and table 2.

I've also been trying to inner join the two tables to make a subquery, then using that inner join for except clause on each of the tables, then stacking the original inner join with the two except unions.

**Current Attempt:** [One Join, Two Excepts, Two Unions](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/576bc/19)

**UPDATE:** I got the current attempt to return values! It's a bit complicated though, Appreciate any advice or feedback though! Great answers below thanks, I will need to do some comparisons

Thanks

Comment: Please include the query attempt(s) you have so far along with a description of what is not working. Please tag your RDBMs (sql server, oracle, etc). Please include sample data for the expected input (table values) and the expected output.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: what is your rdbms? for example mysql doesnt implement full join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(t1.part,t2.part) AS Part,
       ISNULL(t1.operation,t2.operation) AS Operation,
       ISNULL('Estimated Rate',0) AS 'Estimated Rate',
       ISNULL('Actual Rate',0) AS 'Actual Rate'
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.part = t2.part
 AND t1.operation = t2.operation
```

Comment: Does the Estimated Rate and Actual Rate in the third and fourth ISNULL need to reference t1 and t2?

Comment: Also this made me realize how much I was over thinking it. Thanks for the ISNULL! that made things much easier.

Comment: No because the column name is unique in both the table

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as a `union all` and `group by`:

```
select part, operation,
       sum(estimatedrate) as estimatedrate, sum(actualrate) as actualrate
from ((select part, operation, estimatedrate, 0 as actualrate
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select part, operation, 0 as estimatedrate, 0 actualrate
       from table1
      )
     ) er
group by part, operation;
```